# How to read both EPC and USER memory banks using RFID handheld?

Tags: android, rfid, handheld

We are using Handheld Chainway [C4000](https://www.chainway.net/upload/download/b71ddf36-615d-4871-94ea-4b1e3831de1b.pdf) UHF RFID Reader, and [UHF tags](https://www.atlasrfidstore.com/rfid-tag-sample-pack-uhf-passive/).
Those tags contains EPC and USER memory banks, Right now I can read all the tags' EPC memory bank by scanning them using the handheld device.

This is how I read single tag's EPC memory bank

```
RFIDWithUHF mReader = RFIDWithUHF.getInstance();
String strUII = mReader.inventorySingleTag();
String strEPC = mReader.convertUiiToEPC(strUII);
```

And to read USER memory bank I found that I should stop scanning and start it again but with request to read USER memory bank.

Is there anyway that I could read both EPC and USER memory banks at the same time without restart the scanning process again ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get a reply from the manufacturer of the handheld C4000 Chainway RFID UHF reader, And I will post it if there are any one who faced the same problem.

It is a hardware limitation .. the C4000 doesn't support scanning both at the same time. You can only handle it by software, like scanning twice for different sectors, and show both of the data at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that